# Set-AzDiagnosticSetting For Storage account

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-powershell

I'm new to powershell and DevOps pipeline. Here I tried to set DiagnosticSetting for storage account, but I got some issue as I mentioned below. My Powershell script commands are.

```
 $ResourceId = "/subscriptions/'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'/resourceGroups/'xxxxxxxxxxxx'/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"   
$WorkspaceId = "/subscriptions/'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'/resourcegroups/'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'/providers/microsoft.operationalinsights/workspaces/'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'"
$DiagnosticSettingName = "storagediag"
$metric = New-AzDiagnosticDetailSetting -Metric -RetentionEnabled -Category AllMetrics -Enabled

$setting = New-AzDiagnosticSetting -Name $DiagnosticSettingName -ResourceId $ResourceId -WorkspaceId $WorkspaceId -Setting $metric

Set-AzDiagnosticSetting -InputObject $setting -Debug

$metric = New-AzDiagnosticDetailSetting -Metric -RetentionEnabled -Category AllMetrics -Enabled
$readlog = New-AzDiagnosticDetailSetting -Log -RetentionEnabled -Category StorageRead -Enabled
$writelog = New-AzDiagnosticDetailSetting -Log -RetentionEnabled -Category StorageWrite -Enabled
$deletelog = New-AzDiagnosticDetailSetting -Log -RetentionEnabled -Category StorageDelete -Enabled
$Ids = @($ResourceId + "/blobServices/default")
$Ids | ForEach-Object {
    $setting = New-AzDiagnosticSetting -Name $DiagnosticSettingName -ResourceId $_ -WorkspaceId $WorkspaceId -Setting $metric, $readlog, $writelog, $deletelog
        Set-AzDiagnosticSetting -InputObject $setting
    }
```

**Exception type:** PSInvalidOperationException, Message: System.Management.Automation.PSInvalidOperationException: PowerShell is in NonInteractive mode. Read and Prompt functionality is not available.

Comment: The error message is telling you the problem: *PowerShell is in NonInteractive mode. Read and Prompt functionality is not available.*. Your script is prompting for user input. You need to debug your script and identify what's not correct.

Comment: I found above issue, because of ResourceId and WorkspaceId format is wrong. I have added single quotes('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx') for subscription, resource group and storage account. After removed this single quotes, script is working fine.